# Appfuse spring security hasRole() not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, appfuse

I'm trying appfuse and I have added some custom menus in menu.jsp (no doing in menu-config.xml because I would like to add some glyphicon, and struts menu can't do it)

so for hide/show menus I wanted to use  spring security authorized tag

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                         <li>
                            <a href="test.jsp"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                        </li>
</security:authorize>
```

but this tag causes Yike! error(error 500),  nothing showed in the console. even I have

```
<Logger name="org.springframework.security" level="all"/>
<Logger name="org.springframework" level="all"/>
```

in `log4j2.xml.`

If I switch to  `<security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN"`>  it works as expected. however as far as I know, `ifAnyGranted` is deprecated.

I'm curious why I see no error in output console?

I'm using appfuse 3.5  springMVC, running with jetty:run

Comment: Do you have 'use-expressions=true' attribute in http realm description? Like this:  <http realm="Workplan user realm" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" 
           disable-url-rewriting="true">

Comment: oh, you are right, I didn't enabled the Expression-Based Access Control, I added that directive and worked as expected! even I still don't understand why non error showed in the console... I think you should post this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since Alex didn't put the answer, I will post it myself

I had to add the use-expressions="true"  in the http TAG in security.xml

for example